# I understand that PEX plumbing builds up a biofilm in the line. Is there a way to clean the lines to remove the biofilm?

Tags: plumbing

I know that biofilm collects where water travels and sits. Is there a way to safely remove it from my plumbing?

Comment: Don't put contaminated water into the lines in the first place, and be careful about what you "know" .vs. what you "read somewhere on the internet and failed to question adequately"

Comment: A biofilm contains solid organic matter, you are going to need something caustic that dissolves organic matter... probably not something you would want to be in your water lines. I would recommend a concentrated solution of sodium hydroxide (or drain cleaner) to remove all traces of biofilm, but that is going to be far from "safe".

Comment: 1/2 Actually biofilm builds up in most water sources, especially when there is a warm water supply. I worked for more than 40 years in a dental office and part of our routine was to flush the water lines with an expensive product designed to treat the lines (which were pex) morning and evening after a day’s work, to reduce the harmful biofilm in the lines. So it got me to thinking that our home has all pex lines, our refrigerator water dispenser has a pex line and we don’t flush any of it.  But I imagine this bacteria and biofilm also build in these lines.

Comment: 2/2.....We have the city chlorinated water running through the lines as they were in the dental office so it’s not a matter of using a contaminated water supply source. There is lots of vetted research available on biofilm in copper, pex and pvc pipes within domestic water supply but no information on preventive steps to take to remove it or better yet, to prevent the buildup.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, after years of exposure to this dreaded biofilm, your body is building imunity to a wide variety of biological agents that might otherwise have a bad impact on you and your family. Since very few (in America, at least) clean their water supply lines daily, or even annually, maybe it's contributing to our overall health, and we shouldn't be worried about sterilizing everything. Just one guy's thoughts...

Answer (score 2):

There will be some microorganisms coming in continuously in the public water supply. I don't see the benefit of removing biofilm from your own PEX pipes. The requirements of a dental practice are different from a home.

Afik standard home water piping is not set up for convenient introduction of a cleaning agent and subsequent flushing.

Any tap water that needs to be sterile should be boiled before use. An example would be water used for sinus irrigation using a netipot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you flush the system with a water system cleaner suitable for potable water, eg
https://fernox.com/product/lp-sterox-1l/

- Kills bacteria and algae
- Penetrates and removes biofilm
- For drinking water systems, provided LP Sterox is dosed at the recommended level,
  the treated water is safe enough to drink. Once disinfection is complete, there is no need to flush out or neutralise the system.

For primary circuits (boiler to radiators and hot water cylinder heat exchangers) a protector/inhibitor should be used. There is a British Standard document BS7593:2006 Code of Practice for treatment of water in domestic hot water central heating systems.

https://shop.bsigroup.com/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000030133510